# How do I detect hold event for a button?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I would like to add an hold gesture to a C# created button. But all solution that I've found on the internet don't work. I post the part of the code involved the creation of the button:

```
var button = new Button();

button.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(ButtonClickOneEvent);
button.Hold += new TypedEventHandler<GestureRecognizer, HoldingEventArgs>(holder_recon);
```

The `button.Hold` doesn't work and it gives me an error.

For now, I want `holder_recon`, the function that should start when the button is held, give execute `MessageBox.Show("Held")`.

Can you please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May this will help you.

```
var button = new Button();

button.VerticalAlignment = System.Windows.VerticalAlignment.Top;
button.Height = 75;
button.Tag = tag;
button.Background = new SolidColorBrush(colore);
button.HorizontalContentAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Stretch;
button.Click += button_Click;
button.Hold += button_Hold;

private void button_Hold(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e) => MessageBox.Show("Hold");
private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) => MessageBox.Show("Click");
```

Comment: The hold method is missing for me. I only get the option to hover